# How to remap Alt+j as AltTab using AutoHotkey

Tags: windows, windows-7, autohotkey

How to remap Alt+j  as AltTab and Alt+k as Alt + Shift + Tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use right Alt:

```
RAlt & j::AltTab
RAlt & k::ShiftAltTab
```

or left Alt:

```
LAlt & j::AltTab
LAlt & k::ShiftAltTab
```

or both!